# .htaccess parameters - Disallow rule on admin system

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying something new with .htaccess and am experiencing some difficulties.

```
www.domain.com/page
www.domain.com/category/page
www.domain.com/category/section/page
```

I want to use htaccess to use: function.php and grab the 'page' to work up the code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} . 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ function.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem I face is. I don't want this rule to apply on my admin system.
www.domain.com/adminsystem

The second is that for some reason my webfonts when I use the above .htaccess code are not being recognised:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'gibsonregular';
src: url('/css/webfonts/gibson_regular/Gibson-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('/css/webfonts/gibson_regular/Gibson-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('/css/webfonts/gibson_regular/Gibson-Regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('/css/webfonts/gibson_regular/Gibson-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('/css/webfonts/gibson_regular/Gibson-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('/css/webfonts/gibson_regular/Gibson-Regular-webfont.svg#gibsonregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

There are so many tutes on the net re: htaccess but I can't seem to find one that solves my dilemma.

Comment: For `www.domain.com/page` you want `function.php?id=page`. But what about `www.domain.com/category/page` and `www.domain.com/category/section/page` ? Would it be `function.php?id=category/page` or still `function.php?id=page` ?

Comment: Hi justin, Everything will come from function.php and I will include the page according to its menu id.

Comment: Yes but could you simply answer with the example i gave please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below solved my dilemma. Basically it looks to see if an actual file / folder exists. If it does then don't do anything. If it doesn't then do its' job.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^function\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ function.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```